# How to implement this Jupyter notebook on Google Colab?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, google-colaboratory

I just started using Google Colab a few horus ago and I'm trying to figure our how to read,write and save stuff etc.

I have this code on Jupyter notebook,and I'm having trouble at the last part where I save the file, I want to save it either on my local computer or Google Drive?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 999)

#load data

df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\Isolation Forest\\IF 15 PERCENT.csv')
df.shape

#data info
info = df.info()
print(info)


#data description
describe = df.describe()  #print(describe)
f = open('D:\\Project\\database\\Isolation Forest\\Final Description IF TEST11.txt', "w+")
print(describe, file=f)
f.close()
```

and

Google Colab Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
# Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

link = '......'

fluff, id = link.split('=')
print (id) # Verify that you have everything after '='
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id':id}) 
downloaded.GetContentFile('IF 15 PERCENT.csv')  
df = pd.read_csv('IF 15 PERCENT.csv',index_col=None)

info = df.info()
print(info)
describe = df.describe()
```

I don't really know how to save it now as txt file and w+

Thank you.

Comment: Are you downloading from some link?

Comment: @Pygirl The links is to my csv file in my google drive

Comment: What's the problem you are facing ?

Answer (score 0):

**This will save your dataframe in text format:**

```
tfile = open('test.txt', 'w+')
tfile.write(describe.to_string())
tfile.close()
```

Comment: What ever works in your local host will work in colab notebook too if you have mounted your gdrive.

Comment: So I've tried this but the text file is one long sentence instead of being in a column shape.